# how to sum the columns of a weighted dfm in quanteda?

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, quanteda

Consider this funny example

```
mytib <- tibble(text = c('i can see clearly now',
                         'the rain is gone'),
                myweight = c(1.7, 0.005)) 
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  text                  myweight
  <chr>                    <dbl>
1 i can see clearly now    1.7  
2 the rain is gone         0.005
```

I know how to create a `dfm` weighted by the `docvars` `myweight`. I proceed as follows:

```
dftest <- mytib %>% 
  corpus() %>% 
  tokens() %>% 
  dfm()

dftest * mytib$myweight 

Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 9 features (50.0% sparse).
2 x 9 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
       features
docs      i can see clearly now   the  rain    is  gone
  text1 1.7 1.7 1.7     1.7 1.7 0     0     0     0    
  text2 0   0   0       0   0   0.005 0.005 0.005 0.005
```

However the issue is that I cannot use neither `topfeatures` nor `colSums`.

How can sum the values in every column then?

```
> dftest*mytib$myweight %>% Matrix::colSums(.)
Error in base::colSums(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

Thanks!

Comment: `colSums(dftest * mytib$myweight)` works for me.

Comment: crazy stuff. why??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes the `%>%` operator harms rather than helps.  This works:

```
colSums(dftest * mytib$myweight)
##      i     can     see clearly     now     the    rain      is    gone 
##  1.700   1.700   1.700   1.700   1.700   0.005   0.005   0.005   0.005
```

Also consider using `dfm_weight(x, weights = ...)` if you have a vector of weights for each feature.  The operation above will recycle your weights to make it work the way you want, but you should understand why (in R, because of recycling and because of its column-major order).

Answer (score 1):

It would because of operator precedence. If we check the `?Syntax`, special operators have higher precedence compared to multiplication (`*`)

```
...
%any%   special operators (including %% and %/%)  ###
* / multiply, divide   ###
...
```

Wrap the expression inside parens and it should work

```
(dftest*mytib$myweight) %>% 
       colSums
#     i     can     see clearly     now     the    rain      is    gone 
#   1.700   1.700   1.700   1.700   1.700   0.005   0.005   0.005   0.005
```